# How do I troubleshoot this crashing C code?

Tags: c, arrays, while-loop, crash

so I'm working on Euler's Phi function in C programming. Everything seems to be working perfect until I hit this snippet of code and it crashes.

```
while(a[i] != 0 || a[i]!= 1)
        {
            m=m*((a[i]-1)/a[i]);
            i++;
        }
```

Previous to this code the program, user enters a value and then the prime factors are determined.

Comment: You probably want to stop before `i` is bigger than the length of your array.

Comment: What's in the array? Is there some terminating condition embedded in the array?

Comment: probably `||` --> `&&` (because `a[i] != 0 || a[i]!= 1` always true)

Comment: After the prime factors are found I filled up the rest of the array with zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a[i] != 0 || a[i] != 1
```

This is always true since a number cannot be both 0 and 1. You presumably encounter a zero divide condition when `a[i]` is zero.

I guess you meant to write

```
a[i] != 0 && a[i] != 1
```

But I cannot be sure of that since I cannot see the rest of your code. However, this change will avoid the zero divide.